# WCF Performance degrades

Tags: .net, performance, wcf, performance-testing

I was having performance issues with WCF and as a test set the Throttling options to 1000.

```
  <serviceThrottling 
            maxConcurrentCalls="1000" 
            maxConcurrentSessions="1000" 
            maxConcurrentInstances="1000"
          />
```

This worked, processor hit 100% but still served 1200 calls per second (watching perfmon.exe WCF counters).

My problem is that after a while, this performance stops.  Subsequent load tests have the CPU hitting 10% and the max call / instances never hitting 100% and the call per second only hitting 30-40.  The database server is not showing anything during the profile (the call is a simple data lookup).  Queries are executing fast, CPU is low.

I can not determine if there is some other possible bottleneck that I could be missing.

My question is: What other limitation could be causing the bottleneck?

Comment: any outgoing http traffic the the machine?

Comment: Not that I know of.  What sort are you thinking of?  Why do you think the requests per second would drop?